# What qualifies as "open water" with respect to FAR 91.119?

Tags: far-91

FAR 91.119 governs minimum safe altitudes.  It contains a reference to open water.  What qualifies as open water in the eyes of the FAA?

Answer (score 6):

Most probably the same definition as a dictionary's:

***open-water***. An expanse of an **ocean, sea, or large lake** which is distant from shore and devoid of nearby islands or other obstructions.

I searched for a legal definition but I can't find one. It's like defining a sparsely populated area, it's hard to draw a line. So sticking to charts is best I guess.

You might want to search for **maritime laws** that define such boundaries, which are borrowed by aeronautical charts.

On an FAA chart it's depicted like this:

[image]

Source: [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/Chart_Users_Guide_12thEd.pdf)